# Exclude a particular area from geom_smooth fit automatically

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny, plotly

I am plotting different plots in my shiny app.

By using `geom_smooth()`, I am fitting a smoothing curve on a scatterplot.

I am plotting these plots with `ggplot()` and rendering with `ggplotly()`.

Is there any way, I can exclude a particular data profile from `geom_smooth()`.

For e.g.:
[image]

It can be seen in the fit, the fit is getting disturbed and which is not desirable. I have tried `plotly_click()`, `plotly_brush()`, `plotly_select()`. But, I don't want user's interference when plotting this fit, this makes the process much slower and inaccurate.

Here is my code to plot this:

```
#plot
    g <- ggplot(data =  d_f4, aes_string(x = d_f4$x, y = d_f4$y)) + theme_bw() +
          geom_point(colour = "blue", size = 0.1)+
          geom_smooth(formula = y ~ splines::bs(x, df = 10), method = "lm", color = "green3", level = 1, size = 1)
```

Unfortunately, I can not include my dataset in my question, because the dataset is quite big.

Answer (score 0):

You can make an extra data.frame without the "outliers" and use this as the input for `geom_smooth`:

```r
set.seed(8)
test_data <- data.frame(x = 1:100)
test_data$y <- sin(test_data$x / 10) + rnorm(100, sd = 0.1)
test_data[60:65, "y"] <- test_data[60:65, "y"] + 1

data_plot <- test_data[-c(60:65), ]

library(ggplot2)

ggplot(data =  test_data, aes(x = x, y = y)) + theme_bw() +
  geom_point(colour = "blue", size = 0.1) +
  geom_smooth(formula = y ~ splines::bs(x, df = 10), method = "lm", color = "green3", level = 1, size = 1)
```

[image]

```r
ggplot(data =  test_data, aes(x = x, y = y)) + theme_bw() +
  geom_point(colour = "blue", size = 0.1) +
  geom_smooth(data = data_plot, formula = y ~ splines::bs(x, df = 10), method = "lm", color = "green3", level = 1, size = 1)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-11-27 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

BTW: you don't need `aes_string` (which is deprecated) and `d_f4$x`, you can just use `aes(x = x)`

Comment: I am doing all this in shiny app, I am uploading datafiles in the app, that's why I am using 'aes_string' instead of 'aes'.

Comment: Now it is recommended to use the special `.data` variable, see [here](https://mastering-shiny.org/action-tidy.html#example-ggplot2)